# Laravel passport all routes goes to login

Tags: php, laravel

I done a project in Laravel, it works fine on my `localhost` but now I uploaded my project to `cpanel` everything looks fine but I found a problem, that those routes under `auth:api` not open even with `token` ! while those works fine in my `localhost` with `token`

```
Route::middleware(['auth:api', 'can:admin'])->group(function () {
  //...other routes
  Route::get('card/index',[CardController::class, 'index']);
});
```

In postman I run this url with Bearer token:

```
{{domain}}/api/card/index (GET)
```

And it return me an error:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException:
> The GET method is not supported for route api/user/login. Supported
> methods: POST. in file
> /home/project/public_html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php
> on line 122

I know there is not login route defined! but this is no matter! because it should not goes to login at all!

I checked all these:

1. run `composer update` again
2. run `php artisan passport:install` and `passport:client` and `passport:client--personal`
3. run all `cache:clear` things.

Am I missed something?

---

### Update

May need to see AuthServiceProvide, I guess there is somewthing wrong with this gate or passport expiry:

```
public function boot(): void
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(15));
        Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(30));
        Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(now()->addMonths(6));

        Gate::define('admin', function ($user) {
            return $user->role && $user->role->title === 'admin';
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When deploying Passport to your application's servers for the first time, you will likely need to run the passport:keys command. This command generates the encryption keys Passport needs in order to generate access tokens.

```
php artisan passport:keys
```

Comment: `Encryption keys already exist. Use the --force option to overwrite them.` I used --force but still the same issue